# Why do my pages move horizontally (see link)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am supporting a website:

https://www.allcounted.com/

If you first look at the home page or What's Hot page and then click the Subject or Country page in the top navigation, you would see the page move left a little.

I know this is a CSS issue, but I am unable to find out the CSS rules that creates  this issue. This website uses bootstrap-3.2.0 and some other tools.

Comment: Really sorry but can you provide an example of how it looks wrong? I'm unable to see anything different from my end.

Comment: Need to know your browser and resolution of your monitor (or size of your viewport). Unable to replicate in Chrome.

Comment: Garconis, please see Jakub's answer.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my screen this page seems displaying correctly (Chrome 57). This 'movement' what are you talking about's occurring because of browser is scrollbar, I guess, if I m wrong, punish me, but also I may recommend you using Developer Tools at your browser to inspect that. :)

If you could share more info I will be glad. (Some screens etc.)

Comment: Jakub, I am a developer. I used the Chrome Inspect and FF Firebug and did many tests. Was unable to find the reason. The scroll bar issue could be the reason, which I overlooked at. I will do a test with sample content to see whether your input is right. Thanks!

Comment: Jakub, I did a test with Bootstrap and the content has nothing to do with my website. You are perfectly right. No wonder I was not able to fix it:-) Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you. =)

Comment: Also I figured out how you may replace default scrollbar to your own (works only for -webkit-).

There's a link; http://www.gtricks.com/chrome/scroll-bar-without-extension/